# EmberJs: Own View with Value Binding

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to use my own Ember.View implementation but unfortunately the valueBinding does not work (it works with the build-in ones)

```
App.NumberView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'input',

  attributeBindings: ['type', 'min', 'max', 'step', 'value', 'placeholder'],

  type: 'number',
  step: '0.01',
  min: '0',
  max: null,
  placeholder: null,
  value: ''
});
```

In the template:

```
{{view App.NumberView id="value" valueBinding="value" placeholder="39.90"}}
<button type="button" {{action submit}}>submit</button>
```

In the controller:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  submit: function() {
    // returns undefined
    this.get('value');
  }
});
```

What is missing on my own NumberView to support valueBinding?

Bodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending `Ember.View`, you could better extend the `Ember.TextField` directly.

For example:

```
App.NumberView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['type', 'min', 'max', 'step', 'value', 'placeholder'],
  type: 'number',
  step: '0.01',
  min: '0',
  max: null,
  placeholder: null,
  value: ''
});
```

See here for a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ujulug/2/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a start but I would like to know what I missed for a native work

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work natively. There are a couple things wrong here. It didn't work because when you use `this.get('value');` in the controller, it's looking for the attribute 'value' in the controller itself which didn't exist, thus the undefined. Also, 'value' is a reserved property of the Ember View so you can't treat it as the input's value property.

What you have to do is set `valueBinding` of the view to a custom attribute/property in your controller. This will bind the View's value to the Controller (and not the View's Input's value). In order to bind the actual html input's value, you have to manually propagate the changes and set the View's value. I'll explain after this code chunk.

**HTML HBS**:

```
{{view App.NumberView valueBinding="cValue" placeholder="39.90"}}
```

**Javascript**:

```
App.NumberView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.change = $.proxy(this._change, this);
  },
  tagName: 'input',

  attributeBindings: ['type', 'min', 'max', 'step',  'placeholder'],

  type: 'number',
  step: '0.01',
  min: '0',
  max: null,
  value: null,

  _change: function(){
    this.set('value',this.$('input').get('context').value);

    console.log('View input value is --> ' + this.$('input').get('context').value);
  }  
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  cValue: null,
  submit: function() {
    alert(this.get('cValue'));
  }
});
```

So basically, the Controller has a property called cValue, which is binded to the `value` of NumberView. In NumberView, I used didInsertElement() function to attach my own function call `_change()` to the input's change event. In `_change()`, I set and update the NumberView's value to the input's current value.

Here is a working [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/IdIGOrAG/2/edit)